# Using SQL, select a single record from a table for each associated record in it's associated foreign key table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get one latest `Approved` risk assessments (it's a `bit` column) for each department in the department table.

I also need all the not `Approved` risk assessments for all departments but I think I'll probably do that as a separate query or union the two result sets.

Here's a simplified version of my schema for what it's worth.

[image: Department to RiskAssement table diagram]

Comment: What you have so far? What's the question? Or you just want someone to do your job?

Comment: I'd love someone to do my job, are you offering? Don't think that I'm just twiddling my thumbs waiting for someone to reply, I'm searching all the time and I've ended up answering my own question the last few times on SO. I can't really remember where to start with this, it's been a while since I've had to do it. It's hard to get myself started when I can't remember appropriate terms to Google. I suspect that I'll have to do it with a subquery but that's about as far as I've gotten.

Comment: FWIW Common table expressions didn't even exist last time I had to do this so even if I remembered I'd have not found that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have SQL 2005 or higher you can use a CTE to achieve this

```
with cte as (
   select row_number() over (partition by DeptId, order by Submitted desc) as row,
   id,
   DeptId,
   RiskAssessment,
   Submitted,
   Approved
   from RiskAssesment where approved = 1
)

select
   id,
   deptid,
   RiskAssessment,
   Submitted,
   Approved
   from cte where row = 1
```

Comment: @Oscar Thanks for the correction, I can never remember which version provided which!

Comment: You sir...just saved my bacon. Thanks a lot to you Oscar and Ben!

Answer (score 0):

To get the `latest Approved` task you will need Approval time Stored into column in `RiskAssessment` then you can use Group by and max to get the expected results.

For second part

> all the not Approved risk assessments for all departments
>   i think it wil be easier no need to be subquery.

```
Select DEPTID, id where Approved=0
```

if this is not what you mean, I think i didnt understand your question well.